# How does an existing object retrieve it's changes once we update it somewhere else in repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know the title is quite confusing and so is the question. I was working on spring boot with the JPA repository and some unusual behaviour happened. I will explain two cases, both of them have only one difference which shouldn't make any difference but it's causing some unusual behaviour.

I made a repository call to get an object, let's say `obj1` and I made some changes on it and then I passed `obj1` to another function `funcInSameClass(obj1)` which is in the same class and from that function I passed the `obj1` to a function `funcInAutowiredClass1(obj)` of an autowired component `AutowiredClass1`, from that component I passed the Id of `obj1` to another function `funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id)` of autowired component `AutowiredClass2`. And in `funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id)` I made a repository call to get the same object as `obj1` and make some changes in `obj1` and `saveAndFlush` to the database.
Now the following is happening in two different cases:

CASE 1:

```
class MainClass {

  @Autowired
  AutowiredClass1 autowiredClass1;

  public void main() {
    //inital object after first repository call
    Object obj1 = repo.findById(id);
    //make some changes in obj1
    funcInTheSameClass(obj1);
    repo.saveAndFlush(obj1)
    log.info(obj1); //here also obj1 name is still null
  }
  void funcInTheSameClass(Object obj1) {
    autowiredClass1.funcInAutowiredClass1(obj1);
    log.info(obj1); //here also obj1 name is still null
  }
}

class AutowiredClass1 {
  @Autowired
  AutowiredClass2 autowiredClass2;
  public void funcInAutowiredClasss1(Object obj1) {
    autowiredClass2.funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id);
    log.info(obj1); // now here the obj1 name is still null
  }
}

class AutowiredClass2 {
  public void funcInAutowiredClasss2(int id) {
    Object obj2 = repo.findById(id);
    obj2.setName("XYZ");
    repo.saveAndFlush(obj2);
    log.info(obj2); // here I set the obj2 name as "XYZ"
  }
}
```

CASE 2:

```
class MainClass {

  @Autowired
  AutowiredClass1 autowiredClass1;

  public void main() {
    //inital object after first repository call
    Object obj1 = repo.findById(id);
    //make some changes in obj1
    obj1 = repo.saveAndFlush(obj1);
    funcInTheSameClass(obj1);
    repo.saveAndFlush(obj1)
    log.info(obj1); //here also obj1 name is now XYZ
  }
  void funcInTheSameClass(Object obj1) {
    autowiredClass1.funcInAutowiredClass1(obj1);
    log.info(obj1); //here obj1 name is now XYZ
  }
}

class AutowiredClass1 {
  @Autowired
  AutowiredClass2 autowiredClass2;
  public void funcInAutowiredClasss1(Object obj1) {
    autowiredClass2.funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id);
    log.info(obj1); // now obj1 name is now XYZ
  }
}

class AutowiredClass2 {
  public void funcInAutowiredClasss2(int id) {
    Object obj2 = repo.findById(id);
    obj2.setName("XYZ");
    repo.saveAndFlush(obj2);
    log.info(obj2); // here I set the obj2 name as "XYZ"
  }
}
```

You can see there is a difference of one repo call only and it's working in different ways. In the first case, the value of obj1 is not reflected back from funcInAutowiredClass2 to the main function. But in the second case, the value of obj1 is updated. How is this happening?

Comment: See the duplicate, it explains the caching issue working here as well. In your first example `obj1` isn't cached itself it then won't be affected by later changes.

Comment: @Tom why didn't the obj1 in first example didn't cache itself and in the second one it cached itself?

Comment: using crud repository is a good option as well

Comment: @javauser You didn't "add" caching to `obj1` before manipulating it. So it is disconnected from it and stands on its own. But when you read the object from the repository and change it, then you should see that `obj2` changes, because that is now cached