# How did an object fetched the latest value from DB without making a db call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know the title is quite confusing and so is the question. I was working on spring boot with the JPA repository and some unusual behaviour happened.

I made a repository call to get an object, let's say `obj1` and I made some changes on it and then I passed `obj1` to another function `funcInSameClass(obj1)` which is in the same class and from that function I passed the `obj1` to a function `funcInAutowiredClass1(obj)` of an autowired component `AutowiredClass1`, from that component I passed the Id of `obj1` to another function `funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id)` of autowired component `AutowiredClass2`. And in `funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id)` I made a repository call to get the same object as `obj1` and make some changes in `obj1` and `saveAndFlush` to the database.

```
class MainClass {

  @Autowired
  AutowiredClass1 autowiredClass1;

  public void main() {
    //inital object after first repository call
    Object obj1 = repo.findById(id);
    //make some changes in obj1
    obj1 = repo.saveAndFlush(obj1);
    funcInTheSameClass(obj1);
    repo.saveAndFlush(obj1)
    log.info(obj1); //here also obj1 name is now XYZ
  }
  void funcInTheSameClass(Object obj1) {
    autowiredClass1.funcInAutowiredClass1(obj1);
    log.info(obj1); //here obj1 name is now XYZ
  }
}

class AutowiredClass1 {
  @Autowired
  AutowiredClass2 autowiredClass2;
  public void funcInAutowiredClasss1(Object obj1) {
    autowiredClass2.funcInAutowiredClass2(obj1.id);
    log.info(obj1); // now obj1 name is now XYZ
  }
}

class AutowiredClass2 {
  public void funcInAutowiredClasss2(int id) {
    Object obj2 = repo.findById(id);
    obj2.setName("XYZ");
    repo.saveAndFlush(obj2);
    log.info(obj2); // here I set the obj2 name as "XYZ"
  }
}
```

You can see that in the `funcInAutowiredClass2`, reference of `obj1` is not passed but a fresh entity is fetched from the repository and updated and saved. Then how come the changes reflect back in  `main function()`.

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-first-level-cache/ take a look at this article, that's how first level cache works in Hibernate

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov Can you explain how this caching is done here by taking an example from question?

Comment: After the first call `Object obj1 = repo.findById(id);` your entrity exists in PersistenceContext(L1 cache). After each flush - Hibernate synchronize entity state  in Persistence Context with entity state in DB. On the second call of `findById` Hibernate checks cache first. Entity with such ID is already there, so Hibernate grabs cached entrity. Also important thing - Hibernate uses proxies for entities, your obj1 and obj2 are proxies for of the same entity in  Persistence Context. That's why obj1 reflects ALL changes made with the entity

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov Thanks for detailed explaination. Checkout this question, in the case 1 why isn't this scenario applicable there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406919/how-does-an-existing-object-retrieve-its-changes-once-we-update-it-somewhere-el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate have transaction level cache. When you fetch items from db it checks the cache. If it contains entity you fetching such entity will be returned.

Little example to demonstrate.

```
@Transactional
public void someMethod() {
    MyEntity e1 = repository.findById(id);

    // Some other code

    MyEntity e2 = repository.findById(id);

    // Here e1==e2
    // So if you
    e2.setX(1);
    // you will see that
    assert e1.getX() == 1;
    // is true
}
```

Comment: But how does that make changes reflect back in another class after ```saveAndFlush()```, as in this question, It's understandable that after first ```saveAndFlush()``` the entry is stored in cache and when we use ```findById``` for second time the entry from cache is returned but when we make changes in ```obj2``` and use ```saveAndFlush``` then how are these changes reflected back in ```obj1``` in the starting class? We didn't use ```findById``` after making changes for ```obj2```.

Comment: I added example, hope it helps.